# i want to create a url that will direct the link to a login function in my view in django i tried everything and it didn't work

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-admin, django-urls

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.urls import path,include


app_name = 'shop'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),

]
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: I want to add a url path that will redirect a html link to a view

Comment: which django version are you using?

Comment: django version 2.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Code for URLs you are using is for django 1.11 or earlier versions.

You can write URLs like this:

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('dashboard', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
]
```

**views.py**

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

```
def index(request):


  # return render(request, 'index.html'), add path of html page here
  return HttpResponse("This is Home page")


def dashboard(request):

  return HttpResponse("This is Dashboard page")
```